# Mysql SubQuery IN STATEMENT with Parent Col

Tags: mysql

mysql table like this

**TableA**

```
a_id  a_name
1      zone1
2      zone2
3      zone3
.....
```

**TableB**

```
b_id  b_name  FK_id
1     field1  1,2,3
2     field2  2,3
.......
```

**SQL**

```
select b.b_name, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(a.name) 
                       FROM TableA WHERE a_id IN(**FK_id**))  
FROM TableB b 
WHERE b.b_id=1
```

**SQL result:** [field1]  [zone1]

but I change manually SQL like this

```
select b.b_name, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(a.name) 
                  FROM TableA WHERE a_id IN(1,2,3))  
FROM TableB b 
WHERE b.b_id=1
```

**SQL result**: [field1]  [zone1,zone2,zone3]

what is problem I dont understand.

I want to need your advice, thanks

Comment: What do you not understand, what should happen?

Comment: I expect to be first statement, its output is like second result (SQL result: [field1] [zone1,zone2,zone3])

Answer (score 0):

**Don't. Ever. Store. Delimited values int the relational database!**

Instead of storing `a_id`s as a delimited list of values in `TableB` you should've created a pivot (many-to-many) table `TableB_TableA` instead. Your schema would look like

```sql
CREATE TABLE tablea
(
  a_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  a_name VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE tableb
(
  b_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  b_name VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE tableb_tablea
(
  b_id INT NOT NULL, 
  a_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (b_id, a_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (b_id) REFERENCES tableb (b_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (a_id) REFERENCES tablea (a_id)
);
```

Now to get your desired output you would issue the following query

```sql
SELECT b.b_name, GROUP_CONCAT(a.a_name) a_name
  FROM tableb_tablea ba JOIN tableb b
    ON ba.b_id = b.b_id JOIN tablea a
    ON ba.a_id = a.a_id
 WHERE ba.b_id = 1
 GROUP BY ba.b_id
```

Output:

```
| B_NAME |            A_NAME |
|--------|-------------------|
| field1 | zone1,zone2,zone3 |
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af0f6/2)** demo

Absolutely necessary reading

- [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Answer (score 0):

Why is it impossible? this is subquery and "IN" value come from parent col which is 1,2,3.

it is important because if I write "IN" value manually it is work(1,2,3) no problem, 
but SAME value from parent col only one item(1) work.

I have big query, therefore "I must to use" subquery and subquery come multi cols and I concat it in one col.

In addition to, I found some thing If I Use **"NOT" and IN** it work. But this time correct data not come also other data come.

**SQL**

```
select b.b_name, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(a.name) 
                       FROM TableA WHERE a_id **NOT** IN(**FK_id**))  
FROM TableB b 
WHERE b.b_id=1
```